# WP_Query | meta_query argument meta value in array serialize form

Tags: mysql, wordpress, function, plugins

In short i want  get meta values from usermeta table but the meta value is in serialize array form,
these values are post ids actually, this is my working code for single meta value, i want multiple values from serialize array in meta_value

```
 $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
         $key = 'classes'; 
         $single = true; 
         $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
         $user_last; 


    $query_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $output,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'stm-courses',
        'meta_query'    => array(
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'classes',
                                    'value' => $user_last,
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                )
                            )
    );
    print_r( $query_args ); echo "string";
```

the single meta value is working fine but not multiple values

the below is the output of the above query

```
Array ( [posts_per_page] => 3 [post_status] => publish [post_type] => stm-courses [meta_query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => classes [value] => Array ( [0] => 5033 [1] => 5034 ) [compare] => LIKE ) ) ) string
```

and in database the value for meta_key classes is stored something like this

```
a:2:{i:0;s:4:"5033";i:1;s:4:"5034";}
```

the values are dynamically changeable so i need something dynamic logic,
Thanks in advance, pls suggest me any good idea how i do this

Answer (score 0):

```
$meta_query[] = array(
  'key'     => 'classes',
  'value'   => sprintf('"%s"', $user_last),
  'compare' => 'LIKE',
);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Jagan's solution will work.
I've the same problem and if i look in the database, a meta_key in a serialize array are in the row meta_value (of an other meta_key )... Logic.

So if you try to get

```
meta_key => "classes",
```

i think the result will be null.

If someone have a solution to get the value of a meta_key in a serialize array with a wp_query ? I take it !